# Tuple which includes a variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples

I have the following code:

```
template<typename... A>
void queueQuery(std::string query, std::function<void(A...)> callback = nullptr);

template<typename... A>
std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(A...)> queryCallback;

std::queue<queryCallback> queryQueue;
```

I want to make a queue of tuples of strings and functions with variadic number of any given types (pretty complex, I understand).

Is there a way to make this achievable?

I currently get the following error:

```
/databasedispatcher.h:14: error: data member 'queryCallback' cannot be a member template
```

Comment: Please expand to a http://sscce.org -- or in your case, a minimal chunk of code that will generate the error in question.  You do understand that two different `template` instances of a type are unrelated types, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `queryCallback`

```
template<typename... A> 
std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(A...)> queryCallback;
```

as a variable template (which is only C++14 compliant). Are you sure that's what you want?

If you want strict C++11 compliance, then wrap your variable into a struct like below:

```
template<typename... A> 
struct Foo{
    std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void (A...)> > queryCallback;
};
```

Then use it as `do_something(Foo<int, double>().queryCallback);` in a temporary, or
`Foo<int, double> foo; do_something(foo.queryCallback);` Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't that possible in C++11? I mean... a tuple of undetermined number of template types, or with a template type with undetermined number of template types?

Comment: No, you cannot do this in standard C++11, you can only templetize functions or classes.

Comment: Ok. So there is no alternatives at all for my problem. I gotta find another way. Thank you.

Comment: You can wrap it into a `struct`, see my updated code